# Chrome SPDY error when SSL proxying with Charles Proxy on MacOS

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, proxy, charles-proxy

I would like to have Charles decrypt HTTPS traffic when browsing in Chrome on MacOS.

But when I visit a website (for example, https://www.facebook.com), there are errors about `net::ERR_SPDY_COMPRESSION_ERROR` on multiple resources.

**How can I fix this?**

Steps I've followed so far:

1. Open `Keychain Access`, search for `charles` and delete every item mentioning `charles`
2. Open Charles Proxy, chose `Help > SSL Proxying > Save Charles Root Certificate...` and save `charles-ssl-proxying-certificate.pem`
3. Open `Keychain Access` again, click `File > Import Items...`, choose `charles-ssl-proxying-certificate.pem`, click Open.
4. Double click on the new certificate, click `Trust`, then for `When using this certificate:` select `Always Trust`
5. Close the window, and enter my password in the Certificate Trust Settings popup, and click `Update Settings`
6. Close Keychain access.
7. In Charles Proxy, select `Proxy > Proxy Settings...`. Check `Enable SSL Proxying` and enter `*:*` in the Location. Click Ok.
8. Restart Charles and Chrome.
9. Enable MacOS Proxy in Charles.
10. Visit https://www.facebook.com in Chrome incognito window.
11. I see multiple `net::ERR_SPDY_COMPRESSION_ERROR` errors in the Chrome Inspector Console.

I also tried the same steps, except using Install Charles Root Certificate from the Charles Proxy Help menu, but it results in the same problem.

```
Charles 4.0.2
Network: WPA2 WiFi
VPN: no
OS: MacOS 10.12.5
Chrome: 58.0.3029.110
```

Comment: Did you find what the problem was?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Charles to version 4.2.7 solved the problem for me (version 4.0.2 had the problem). I think the fix is included in 4.2.5 improvements: SSL Proxying support extended to Port Forwarding and non-HTTP SOCKS traffic.